# MySQL duplicate key on for deleted key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, on-duplicate-key

We have a table of the following structure,

```
CREATE TABLE `DateTracker` (
  `ReferenceType` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `LastRunDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ReferenceType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table will be updated based on the data generated on the other tables and the last date of the data availability.

For e.g., if we've a table called users,

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user` (`Id`,`Username`,`Date`) VALUES (1,'user1','2018-06-22');
INSERT INTO `user` (`Id`,`Username`,`Date`) VALUES (2,'user2','2018-06-24');
```

Then as the last processed entry is having the date as `'2018-06-24'`, we will have a records in the `DateTracker` table as,

```
INSERT INTO `DateTracker` (`ReferenceType`,`Date`,`LastRunDate`) VALUES ('User','2018-06-24','2018-06-28 12:56:37');
```

Now when we delete the entry in `DateTracker` table manually, the script which generates this data will create a new entry and it will be updated on the further running of the script.

The problem is, sometimes it is showing `"1062: Duplicate entry 'User' for key 'PRIMARY'"` when we insert it after the deletion, but there's is actually no row present in the `ReferenceType` column `'User'`.

I'm totally confused why I got this error. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the script which generates this data  - what's that then?

Comment: @P.Salmon That's a shell script which will insert into the `DateTracker` table on successful completion of insertion into User table. But even if I try manually through workbench this occurs.

Comment: There is obviously an error in your script and we cannot really tell you where without seeing the code. Since you can reproduce the problem through workbench, please add those queries, to give us an idea where the problem may come from (as it is currently unclear, at least to me, what you/the script are trying to do exactly). My best guess is that the usertable has a trigger that updates/inserts the datetracker itself, so I would check for a trigger first.

Comment: That's the same insert `DateTracker` query I pasted above

Comment: Please include how you check that the row exists. Run a delete for that row. Insert again. Does that work? We really do not know what your script does. It can be anything from failed/incomplete deletes (or checks for it in your code), effects of a transaction, inserting twice, inserting two rows (e.g. "all rows where there is no larger date" gives you 2 rows if you have the max date twice) or a trigger or other event (that e.g. inserts missing rows every 15 minutes). Short of the script, we need some sample code how you reproduce the situation, so we can (maybe) narrow down potential suspects.